# Seeking advice on how to successfully submit a Nativescript 7 app to the AppStore

Tags: nativescript, ios14

Checking with the community to find out if anyone has been able to get a Nativescript 7 app submitted and successfully reviewed by Apple since iOS 14 was released. We have only found this work around so far.

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8937

Any other suggestions super appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not a place to conduct informal developer surveys.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I edited to make this a question as opposed to a survey. We are seeking advice on how to resolve and are willing to participate in the solution if need be.

Comment: @jmargolisvt  I am not sure how this is not under "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is:" for SO. There was a major flaw in the Nativescript compiler that we helped resolve in the Nativescript Slack board because we reached out about the issue we were having, saving many engineers who were simultaneously encountering the same issue, or would have, many hours of their lives. I am not sure what the intent or purpose of voting this down was, but in my opinion, this was completely unnecessary and antithetical of the value of the SO Nativescript community.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way, but since you are new to the community I understand that you are not fully aware of how your question falls outside community guidelines. It's further evidence that your question was off-topic that you accepted an answer that was merely the result of someone googling the issue for you with no further information provided. This is a clear indicator that your question was neither specific enough nor well-researched. I'm sure that as you spend more time here, you'll get used to how to write a question that fits the guidelines.  Welcome aboard!

Comment: @jmargolisvt I am not new to the community - my profile is!I have been on SO for many many years. I respectfully disagree completely with you on this and I am still unclear what your intent is here. Do you code in Nativescript? Let's assume for a moment I was new, how does this question not fall under "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is:". Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It sounds like the issues you are having are with a few bugs in the Nativescript 7 runtime. Here are a few things that you should try:  [Workaround](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8937#issuecomment-704195133)  and https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8937#issuecomment-705707991

Let me know if that works :-)